# 301 Redirect without Query String (Wordpress)

Tags: .htaccess, server

I switched a client's website from concrete5 to Wordpress and we have a bunch of links on google and other sites that now are 404. We are trying to redirect as many of those links as we possibly can.

We put as many of them in our .htaccess file such as

```
Redirect 301 /news-articles/community/?cat=6 http://our-site.ca/news-articles/community/
Redirect 301 /news-articles/community/2015-in-the-community/?cat=1 http://our-site.ca/news-articles/community/2015-in-the-community/ 
Redirect 301 /news-articles/accident-benefits-update/?cat=5 http://our-site.ca/news-articles/accident-benefits-update/
```

we noticed that if they have a query string at the end of the old URL's and we tried to google around for a solution but everything we found has to do with one kind of url being redirected. and we have hundreds.

EDIT: If we keep the ?cat=5 or whatever the query string is, it breaks wordpress and goes to our 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match the query string in a `Redirect` directive. Try using mod_rewrite instead, so that you can match the query string with the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=6$
RewriteRule ^news-articles/community/$ http://our-site.ca/news-articles/community/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=1$
RewriteRule ^news-articles/community/2015-in-the-community/$ http://our-site.ca/news-articles/community/2015-in-the-community/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCOnd %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=5$
RewriteRule ^news-articles/accident-benefits-update/$ http://our-site.ca/news-articles/accident-benefits-update/? [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to remove the leading slash of the regex pattern in the rule.

Comment: @BrandonStewart Sorry, left out the `?` at the end of the redirected URLs

Comment: You're my hero! Spent so much time trying to get this to work and this fixes it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with http://www.htaccessredirect.net/  .htaccess file.

eg:

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 /news-articles/community/?cat=6 /news-articles/community/
```